# Can't enable Microsoft Update - IE directs me back to Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-7-upgrade

I've just upgraded XP to Win7 Enterprise (via Vista). In Windows Update Control Panel applet, it says that updates are only enabled for Windows and provides a hyperlink to enable it for other products.

When I click either it, or directly run `iexplore http://update.microsoft.com/microsoftupdate` as per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/901037/how-to-enable-and-to-disable-microsoft-update , it redirects me to http://www.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/thanks.aspx?thankspage=5 which tells me to go back to Control Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Pitsch at http://blog.unidesk.com [solved this:](http://blog.unidesk.com/how-to-enable-windows-updates-all-windows-products)

> The problem is the web page that is pulled up is not compatible with
>   IE11. Go figure that one of Microsoft's own web pages isn't
>   compatible.  So enabling compatibility mode or adding Microsoft.com to
>   the compatibility list solves the issue.  Now the proper page comes up
>   and can enable Windows Update to update other Microsoft products. 
>   Keep in mind that in some testing you did have to enable the Windows
>   Update add-on when IE came up.  Enable the add-on, close IE, and click
>   the link again and you should get the proper page.
>
> Now the nice thing is, with Windows 8, this isn't even a concern
>   because checking for updates for other Microsoft products is simply a
>   check box when you 'Change Settings'.

The dialog to enable Compatibility Mode for `microsoft.com` is in IE, `<cogswheel button>->Compatibility Mode settings`.